Create Gradient Porosity
I would like about the method of creating Gradient Porosity Modeling in a cube, where these holes are gradually distributed from one side and vice versa. What is the procedure with Geometry nodes for achieving this effect?


Hello Saled, do the holes can overlapping?

No overlapping.

You can have a look here: Generate non-overlapping spheres having different diameters in a mesh

Notice the distribution of voids in this image, there is a gradient in the distribution.          

Do you want just a 2D distribution in a square or a full 3D distribution in a cube ?

Distribution 3D in cube.

the simpler way, I can think of, to achieve what you want is to use a gradient of Merge by Distance but since this node doesn’t accept gradient, a simple Repeat Zone can be helpful. As your blue print shows you need a Spherical gradient of sizes. So the main idea is use spheres centered on the Cube. With each Iteration the radius of sphere shrink by one unit (depend on the iteration number). With 20 Iterations you will have 19 concentric spheres of course (the last one having a radius of zero, it’s a point). Each sphere will determine the Distance of a Merge by Distance node. The bigger the sphere is the smaller the Distance is. Then you can tweak the Distance with a Map Range to ensure there is no bubbles overlapping. Note that the Distance is depending on the number of iterations, so you will have to tweak the Range Map every time you change the Iteration number.

So let’s begin by a Mesh to Volume on the cube and a Distribute Points in Volume to generate random points.

Now let’s calculate the bubbles radius, for this we need to know the maximum distance from the center of the cube. A point at the center, a Geometry Proximity and a Attribute Statistic will do just that. Then by subtracting this value by the Distance of the Geometry Proximity we invert those values. Then if we divide those values by the maximum, it is normalized. So we can multiple by the maximum radius we want.

we get inside the Repeat Zone node: First we establish a counter that will serve to decrement the radius of the spheres, just by adding one to it self every iterations. Then we divide it by the iteration number. In order to have a good radius of the decremented sphere we have to multiple this value by the maximum value of the Attribute Statistic. Then plug it on the threshold of a Greater Than with the value on the Subtract of the bubbles radius. Then use it as Selection on the Merge by Proximity node. Now we have to determine the Distance of the Merge by Proximity node: We Multiply our Counter by the Maximum Radius, plug it in the Map Range in order to tweak this distance.

The rest is classical Instances on Points, Realize Instances and a Mesh Boolean…

And the all node three:

And the .blend:

Edit for cylinder:


Thank you very much for the idea, but in my case as shown in the figure, the parallel holes (cylindrical holes) in a 3D cube

Do you want me to edit the blend?

If possible please.

Thank you very much, In the case of linear gradient, how would you adjust the Geometry nodes to accommodate holes on an cube?

I am not sure of witch linear gradient you are talking... The radius of th tubes are based on the distance: it's a linear gradient. As well the steep gradient of the Merge by distance follow a linear incrémentation so it's also "linear" in a way...

Do you mean something like that???
https://blend-exchange.com/b/kXWwXzJn/

Like this: 

You just replace th central point by a side line (with many points): https://blend-exchange.com/b/JOyoxxBm/

Very well, thank you very much. Last question, in the case where these cylinders are replaced with spheres, for instance, the large spheres are located at the center of the cube and the small ones at the edges of this cube, how do I modify this node? I tried replacing the 'cylinder' node with 'sphere', but it doesn't work.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
